# How to debug multi-threading'ly in InteliJ?

Tags: android, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea, android-debug

I know that Eclipse has pretty nice (as If we can say , multi-thread is nice..) ability to debug distinct threads, with stop/start and detailed info about threads. How about InteliJ idea, is there any plugin or something to do that? Every time I start from main new thread, I see output from methods but never access these methods(neither implemented run() method) to debug, even placing brakepoints in almost every line.